# Is there a way to test the type of content in an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeof

I am trying to test the type of content in an element using javascript / jquery but whenever I get the content out of the element, it is always returned as a string:

```js
$('.test').each(function() {
    console.log(
      this.innerHTML.trim(), 
      typeof this.innerHTML, 
      typeof $(this).text(), 
      $.type(this.innerHTML.trim()),
      Number.isInteger(Number(this.innerHTML.trim()))
    );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
1234
</div>
<div class="test">
22.54
</div>
<div class="test">
2test
</div>
```

Is there a way to test the type without using `typeof` so that I can parse the numbers so I can do a sort on them properly, rather than sorting them as strings

Comment: You need `Number.isInteger(Number(this.innerHTML.trim()))`.

Comment: Are you checking only integer type or it includes other type of values also?

Comment: @Lalit I need to check for float, integer and string and parse accordingly so the sort works properly

Comment: Why do you need to distinguish between integers and floats when sorting?

Comment: @Xufox if I parse a float as an integer will it parse properly, if not then the sort won't work?

Comment: @Pete Just use `Number(`…`)` as I used it. Then sort with `(a, b) => (a - b)` or `(a, b) => (Number(a) - Number(b))` for numbers. There’s really no reason to use `parseInt` or `parseFloat` here.

Comment: @Xufox Ah yes, that works! think I was trying to go too granular.  If you want to add that as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is check func for typeof :

```js
$('.test').each(function() {
  
    var checktype = isNaN( this.innerHTML )
    if (checktype == false) { alert("number"); return;}
    else {
    
    alert( typeof this.innerHTML )
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
1234c
</div>
<div class="test">
22.54
</div>
```

Comment: Hahaha `isNaN` that's what I was looking for, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can for instance use function `isNaN` to check if text (it also accepts strings) is not a number. If it's number `parseFloat` or `+` sign to parse your variable to desired type.

```js
$('.test').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    if(!isNaN(text))
     text = +text;
    console.log(text + " " + typeof text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
1234
</div>
<div class="test">
22.54
</div>
<div class="test">
normalText
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `parseInt` before check `isInteger`.

```js
$('.test').each(function() {
     console.log(Number.isInteger(parseInt(this.innerHTML.trim())))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
1234
</div>
<div class="test">
22.54
</div>
```

Comment: You mean `parseFloat` or `Number`.

Comment: Unfortunately if you use parse int and number.isinteger, it would return true for things like "2test"